# Whats the best windows explorer add in for Skydrive?

Tags: windows-explorer, onedrive

I'm looking for good/safe/reliable windows explorer add in to use with SkyDrive.

I found and I'm using [Gladinet](http://www.gladinet.com/p/download_starter_direct.htm) which allowed dragging of a folder plus contents into SkyDrive, but not dragging of folders containing folders, its working but it has also failed to transfer a few times as well.

Anything better? That can drag folders containing other folders? Any comment on how safe they are (as you obviously need to enter your windows live password)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hadn't used this myself, but I found [SkyDrive Explorer](http://skydriveexplorer.com/).  I found some others but they didn't look as polished, and I hadn't used them, so I am not listing them.

I hope this work for you.

Comment: I tried this but it didnt work dragging folders, was I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Skydrive itself supplies [such a sync app that you can download](https://g.live.com/8SESkyDrive/SkyDriveApps) now for Windows, Mac, and multiple mobile platforms. On Windows this allows you to drag a folder into the create Skydrive folder and have the whole folder tree get uploaded/synced to your Skydrive. And Windows 8 has a browser integrated as an app, but this does not currently do what you ask.

Comment: My experience with this app isn't great. On 3 different machines and crashes usually on 2 out of the 3 and occasionally on the third.

Comment: @CJM - The final version has not even been releaed yet.  I assume your experience with the application was during the WIndows 8 beta.

Comment: I have Windows 8 RTM running on a Samsung Slate 7 tablet right now.

Comment: I was actually on about the app for other Windows OSes: https://apps.live.com/skydrive/app/9a65e47d-606a-4816-a246-90f54bf7a3ea. But as it happens, I've had Win 8 Pro on one laptop for nearly 3 weeks, running Skydrive (seems to be OK, albeit with little use so far).

Comment: Using this on Windows 7 has been seamless for me.